# A lot of my old PDF files have become unreadable, and pdftk doesn't seem to help

Tags: pdf, pdftk

I have an extensive library of my old publications in PDF format.  Recently I found that many of the older ones (as recent as early 2000s) are no longer readable by either `okular` or `xpdf`.  `xpdf` says:

```
Syntax Error: Couldn't find trailer dictionary
Syntax Error: Couldn't find trailer dictionary
Syntax Error: Couldn't read xref table
```

`okular` just says `could not open file`.

`pdftk <myfile.pdf> dump_data` yields:

```
Warning: failed to read page tree. Corrupt input.
Warning: no info dictionary found
PdfID0: 279c83a9e63f742d449fa2766c5cd925
PdfID1: 279c83a9e63f742d449fa2766c5cd925
NumberOfPages: 1
PageMediaBegin
PageMediaNumber: 1
PageMediaRotation: 0
PageMediaRect: 0 0 612 792
PageMediaDimensions: 612 792
```

More recent files (from the early 2000's) fail differently.
Everything later than 2010 is fine.
All the files are roughly the expected size.

Any idea what might be going wrong?

Comment: Can Adobe Reader read and show them? If it does, then it's a bug worth reporting.

Comment: There are a bunch of tips [here](https://superuser.com/questions/278562/how-can-i-fix-repair-a-corrupted-pdf-file) for repairing PDF files. I might try some of them, esp. ghostscript.

Comment: Do you have backup copies of your old PDFs? because I think you're going to need them. BTW, problems like are one of the reasons why some people (including me) like to use error-detecting and error-correcting filesystems like ZFS or btrfs.  Even plain old RAID is better than nothing. Note, though, that zfs/btrfs/raid and the like are still not a replacement for regular backups. Disks die, power can fail, computers can crash or be hacked or infected with malware, houses get burgled or burn down or get flooded etc, and children/cats/etc can "accidentally" type `sudo rm --no-preserve-root -rf /`.

Comment: Is there any correlation between the failed files, and the version numbers as shown by `file *.pdf` ?

Comment: Have they ever been transferred (e.g. by FTP), with any possibility of CRLF conversions ?

Comment: I have of course 3 or 4 different backups of each, on different devices; but apparently the backups were made AFTER the files became corrupted, probably in the early 2000s, so all the copies are identical.  I suspect this may have been part of my migration from VAX VMS to non-VAX VMS to assorted UNIXes and finally to a long line of different Linux distros.  I recall some vulnerabilities in file transfers from VMS to "other".  As you might deduce from the above sequence, I don't do Windows.  I used to have "acroread" but it doesn't seem to be available in modern Linux repositories.

Comment: I have a single PDF, originally created in pdfFactory Pro 3.17 (Windows XP Professional Chinese) in 2008 which is accessible in Xreader.
PDF document, version 1.2